# Is there a way to experimentally separate the effects of gate voltage?

Tags: semiconductors, physics

I'm currently doing experiments on new kind of semiconductors. These devices have a body (source, drain) and a top gate.

These devices show a response to gate voltage. The conductance changes with respect to gate voltage. Exploring at these features is an avenue for new physics. The gate current is small (pA).

But the conductance change is also small. I was wondering, whether this change is from the actual physics of the material or is it simply due to leakage current.

Is there a way to separate the effects of leakage experimentally ?

Comment: I can't tell what you're even asking here. It sounds like you're just describing MOSFETs and then claiming something about new physics. VTC as unclear, for now.

Comment: I'm sure there is. Maybe get a Masters in Electrical engineering and specialize in microelectronics device design. I'm sure you'll learn what you need to know then.

Comment: @Hearth. I'm asking, of there is a way to separate the effects of leakage current in gate based devices experimentally.

Comment: Can you fabricate devices that have different leakage resistances? Then you could see whether the effect correlates more strongly with the voltage or with the current. If it's voltage based, then changing the leakage resistance won't make much difference. If it's current based, it will.

Comment: charge bias controlled switches have both a charge level Q during output transition that results in a non-linear capacitance. So current is a function of both DC and dV/dt.  The Ron*C is a figure of merit.

Comment: @RJR. I realize now that this may not be the right forum to ask. Since this maybe too much state of the art. FYI: I'm currently doing my PHD. And I can't find answer anywhere. If you feel, this question  is not appropriate for the forum. Let me know.

Comment: It's not the the questions is inappropriate. It's that you've provided so little information (thinks like the structure of the device, doping, applied voltages, bonding methods, etc.) that it reads like something someone's doing in his shed with little to know knowledge about semiconductors. Generally, the methods used to distinguish measurement effects from 'real' physical phenomena depend highly on the design of the experiment and the properties of the device under test.

Comment: @immibis. Thats an excellent point. i did do that by changing the gate thickness. Unfortunately, changing the gate thickness doesn't really affect the leakage current too much in my case. The current is in the range of pA and looks like noise. So, I don't have a lot of control on leakage current. The gate just seems too good.

Comment: As an example - if this is ohmic leakage, then, if you know that your device is expected to have a non-linear response, you can graph the current and determine whether there is a linear effect that can be subtracted from the results.

Comment: Most of us do not know secret new developments. But we can read datasheets of established components. Is your component a generally available one or is it a prototype new development or is it a new artificial class of existing and maybe forthcoming components which have a common factor: One of the electrodes is or will be named = "gate" ? It looks like you are searching some common, but never generally noticed math law which is valid for the members of the class and is the reason why one of the electrodes has got name "gate".

Comment: Does it rise with 'K?

Comment: @RJR. Sorry, if this is a little mysterious. This unfortunately is a sensitive research project. Therefore the secrecy. Also, I don't think the material properties need to be a critical parameter here. The question is much more generalized. The device: You can picture it to be GaAs or InP or Graphene or any other conducting film. I don't see how that would make a big difference in experimental techniques. About your next comment: Noted the idea. I will think about it.

Comment: You'll probably want to get your hands on a Keithley femptoamp meter

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75. Sorry, I don't get your question. Did you mean temperature ?

Comment: sub-threshold leakage current may be temperature dependent

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75. I don't think you got the question at all. Sub threshold leakage is different from gate leakage (You can google). And, unfortunately I don't have my hands on femtoampmeter. I will have to do with what I have.

Comment: @user287001. You're right. I might try another forum as well. Again. I don't see, how the question is connected to underlying material. In my view, it is not too much connected to the material in question. It is about experimental techniques.

Comment: you may have read this https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hu/PUBLICATIONS/PAPERS/783.pdf

Comment: You can LFP noise and do Vgs vs  Ids/Igs curves  , might be useful http://bsim.berkeley.edu/bsim-mg-faq/

Comment: @Qwwerty Can you also calculate what the effects of the gate leakage alone would be and subtract that from your measurements?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of leakage you are concerned with. If it's gate leakage, you can measure that directly (at least at DC and room temperature). 5pA is not all that small. A (relatively) inexpensive op-amp such as the [LMC6001](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snos694i/snos694i.pdf) has a guaranteed maximum bias current of 25fA which is 200 times lower than your estimated leakage.

You need to take precautions to get that performance, and follow recommendations from the manufacturer (National was the original source) and gurus such as Pease.

You can also buy an electrometer type instrument (as suggested in the comments), and that will take care of some of the problems and promise higher performance, but there will still be recommendations to follow to measure currents like that without excessive error.

If you have to make AC measurements it may get much trickier.

Comment: I apologize, if I wasn't clear. I can certainly measure the gate leakage current. That's not a problem at all. But, how do I know whether the properties of my device is due to internal physics or simply due to the effects of gate leakage ? Is there an experimental way to separate the effects of gate leakage ?

Comment: Can the gate leakage be reduced (eg. by modifying the device) leaving the electric field in place? I'm not sure how you can separate the effects externally. When you apply a certain voltage to the gate the leakage is what it is for a given device, there is just a single value of that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the Vg vs Ig averaged to eliminate noise for different output  voltage vs current ranges and get correlation from slow sweeps in both directions, then the data will show it.  You might expect hysteresis, thermal effects and stray noise interference.  Then you can plot the Vg and gm effects as well as reverse leakage effects if any. I.e. supply dependent gate leakage on drain.

The other thing you can measure is the spectral density of the noise from very low frequencies or a relaxation oscillation noise than increases with bias if this is a graphene dielectric. I would expect this to occur before breakdown voltage as it ramps up in rep rate rapidly. This avalanche noise effect would be Partial discharge from contaminants and might occur with a sensitivity below 50mV per nanometer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a three terminal component X prototype, there's no other connections to it than its three terminals S, D and G (worknames, this isn't a mosfet)

This really is an assumption, it isn't said explicitly in preceding question nor comments.

I guess X seems to be stable ie. terminal currents take certain values which seem to follow some still unknown functions of voltages between the terminals and GND and temperature.

Applying the the first assumption and Kirchoff's laws one can remove one current and one voltage out of the variable set. The remaining unknown operating law of X must formally be a pair of equations: Ig=U(Vg,Vd,T) , Id=Y(Vg,Vd,T). Terminal S is the formal ground. T is material temperature. Ig and Id must have a defined positive directions. Let them be into component X.  U and Y are unknown functions.

Assuming the material temperature, Vg and Vd are controllable and the transients stabilize fast enough you should be able to measure a huge cloud of value points (Ig,Id,Vg,Vd,T). Vg and Vd are supplied from programmable precision voltage sources for it.

You obviously have access to software which analyzes the cloud, finds a linearized versions of U and Y in any operating point and also shows error marginals. An alternative is to get a proper mathematician to write the calculation formulas. This isn't a trivial task!

If you find in some operating point substantial and accurate partial derivative Id versus Vg you have separated a transfer conductance. Is it leakage or active phenomena? It's active phenomena at least if it's positive .

If the transfer conductance is negative it can still be active phenomena. This is the case if it's absolute value is higher than the input conductance  ie. the increase of gate voltage reduces drain current more than gate current increases.

If the transfer conductance remains in unsure area ie. between 0 and minus input conductance, it can be considered as internal current distribution change.

Practical electricians obviously do not bother to read the writing above. They would say rather "have AC component in Vg, if you can get power gain, it works" So, input say 10Hz AC signal with a DC level to Vg. Calculate the power flow between X and Vd source. You get gain if the non-DC component of that power flow is more than the inputted AC power.

There can be some latching mechanism which occurs as memory, the component has states like a thyristor. Detecting them needs large slow swings for both Vg and Vd. Some operating point Id,Vd can be unreachable due state transitions. In latched state it's well possible that you see no active operation, getting into it was the active thing and only during it there was power gain.